# Append arrays in OPL-Cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

Imagine I have an arrays as below.

```
int a[1..4]=[1,2,3,4];
int b[1..2]=[5,6]
```

1)If I need to create a array c as below,(1 row and 6 columns)

```
int c[1..6]=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

2)IF I need to create a 2D array using above 2 arrays. Eg: Concatenate above 2, 1D arrays and making a (2 Rows x 3 columns array)

int d[1..2][1..3]=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Could you advise how I can get the outputs from Cplex.

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question is this:

```
int a[1..4]=[1,2,3,4];
int b[1..2]=[5,6];

int c[i in 1..6] = (i <= 4) ? a[i] : b[i - 4];
int d[i in 1..2][j in 1..3] = c[(i - 1) * 3 + j];

main {
  writeln(thisOplModel.c);
  writeln(thisOplModel.d);
}
```

However, for `c` you may be better of using sets. They provide a union operation.

Comment: hi @DanielJunglas  cant we use append to create this output.And if you can provide me a source that I can study about concatenation using (example:  (i <= 4) ? a[i] : b[i - 4] ) these syntax it would be great.I couldnt find a place that the OPL user guide inform these things.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, to concatenate you could also use `int c[0..5] = append(a, b)`. The syntax I used in my example for concatenation is just the ternary operator `?:`. This operator is listed here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/opl_operators.html but I don't think there is an explicit example since it is a standard operation, just like + or -.